# dask dataframe,to_parquet creates a 10 kb file first and then creates rest of the files

Tags: dask

When dask dataframe's  to_parquet is called,  a small parquet file of 10 kb is immediately created. Then other files of size 100 MB are created.  Not sure how this small file was created. my intent is to create the files with uniform size.

Also I'm missing one row count between  source csv and output parquet files.

```
def ProcessPQ(aDfChunk, output_pqfolder):
    fPQfile = os.path.join(output_pqfolder,"{}.parquet".format(str(uuid.uuid1())))    
    aDfChunk.to_parquet(fPQfile, compression="snappy")
def ConvertTxttoPQ(aLocation,aFilePattern,aColumns,aDTypes):
    files=os.path.join(aLocation, aFilePattern)    
    df = dd.read_csv(files, dtype=aDTypes, header=None,sep='|', names=aColumns)
    df2 = df.repartition(npartitions=2)
    df2.map_partitions(ProcessPQ, aObjFileInfo.outputfilelocation).compute(num_workers=3)
```

Comment: This seems to be related to https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2265 . But I passed the meta as suggested by the link. Still I end up having extra partition and value error for couple of columns ( converting string to float) . The Dask library seems to add foo for columns

Comment: I recommend providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)